# A column in the predicate of the SQL

Tags: sql

How can I select custType in the predicate section of the query
I can't do so now because 
Error code -1, SQL state 42X04: Column 'CUSTTYPE' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'CUSTTYPE' is not a column in the target table.

```
select p.SKU AS GiftID, p.ProductName AS GiftName,  
       case   when  sa.Sales >= v.LevelUpAmount then 1 else 2 end AS custType 
       from products p, campaign ca, SubCategory sc,
            VIPLevelUpParam v, 
            ActiveParam a, customer c, 
            (select c.CustomerCode, sum(od.NetSales) AS Sales from customer c  
               INNER JOIN orders o ON (c.CustomerCode = o.CustomerCode) 
               INNER JOIN order_details od ON (o.OrderCode = od.OrderCode)
                   group by c.CustomerCode ) sa                            
               where  ca.CUSTOMERTYPE = custType AND
                 c.CustomerCode = 'CUS000001-2013-11-06' AND
                 p.SubCategoryID = sc.SubCategoryCode AND
                 p.SKU = ca.GiftID AND
                 sc.SubCategoryName = 'Gift'AND 
                 v.LevelUpID = a.ActiveID AND 
                 a.TableName = 'VIPLevelUpParam' 
                 group by p.SKU, p.ProductName, sa.Sales, v.LevelUpAmount, custType;
```

Any one shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't believe the inner SQL sees the outer SQL's ``CUSTTYPE`` defenition

Answer (score 0):

As per logical query processing where clause is evaluated before select statement that why you're getting CustType column won't be available in where clause.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

```
select * from
(
select p.SKU AS GiftID, p.ProductName AS GiftName,  
       case   when  sa.Sales >= v.LevelUpAmount then 1 else 2 end AS custType 
       from products p, campaign ca, SubCategory sc,
            VIPLevelUpParam v, 
            ActiveParam a, customer c, 
            (select c.CustomerCode, sum(od.NetSales) AS Sales from customer c  
               INNER JOIN orders o ON (c.CustomerCode = o.CustomerCode) 
               INNER JOIN order_details od ON (o.OrderCode = od.OrderCode)
                   group by c.CustomerCode ) sa  
) DT
 where  DT.CUSTOMERTYPE = DT.custType AND
                 DT.CustomerCode = 'CUS000001-2013-11-06' AND
                 DT.SubCategoryID = DT.SubCategoryCode AND
                 DT.SKU = DT.GiftID AND
                 DT.SubCategoryName = 'Gift' AND 
                 DT.LevelUpID = DT.ActiveID AND 
                 DT.TableName = 'VIPLevelUpParam' 
                 group by DT.SKU, DT.ProductName, DT.Sales, DT.LevelUpAmount, DT.custType;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a saviour, I have to stay overnight.